# codeigniter simplepie

Tags: codeigniter, simplepie

I wanted to mention, i have simplepie working in my development environment but as soon as I uploaded the site I cannot get feeds into my homepage. Any ideas? here is the code that works on localhost:

```
function Homepage()
{
   parent::Controller();
   $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
   $this->css = $this->config->item('css');
   $this->images = $this->config->item('images');
   $this->load->library('simplepie');
   $this->simplepie->set_feed_url('http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/world/rss.xml');          
   $this->simplepie->set_cache_location(APPPATH.'cache/rss');
   $this->simplepie->init();
   $this->simplepie->handle_content_type();
}

function index()
{
  $data['rssdata'] = array(
    "title" => $this->simplepie->get_title(),
    "description" => $this->simplepie->get_description(),
    "items" => $this->simplepie->get_items(0,5)
    );
    $this->load->view($data)
}

this is the code that is in the view:

 <h3 class="ui-widget-header"><?= $rssdata['title']?></h3>
<div id="accordion" >
<div>
<h5><?= $rssdata['description']?></h5>
<p><?php foreach($rssdata['items'] as $item) :?>
<ul>
<li><?php anchor($item->get_link(),$item->get_title());?></li>
<li class="rssfeed"><?php echo $item->get_description();?></li>
</ul>
<p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y g:i a');?></small></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the library uploaded also?

Comment: yes uploaded. this really bums me out? any clues please?

Comment: If the code works in the dev and not in the prod environment the problem is not in the code. Do you have error suppression in the prod environment? If so try to output some errors and they should give you a clue to what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks frankie will try that and see what shows up. will post what shows up on here so "GUYS" PLEEEAAASE keep checking back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the newest "bleeding edge" from their GitHub profile, it sorts out several problems with PHP 5.3 which were making Apache explode from too many errors.

At time of writing, the bleeding edge is marked as [v1.2.1-dev](http://github.com/rmccue/SimplePie/zipball/master).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem once, when my hosting setup did not have cURL installed, and error_reporting was off....

try setting `var $force_fsockopen = false;` to `var $force_fsockopen = true;` in the SimplePie config file to see if it makes a difference

Comment: hi ekhaled, did what you suggested and nothing. error suppression is something I think is messing with what i can do. I will keep pluggin away though and see what happens